# A function to shift the elements of an array one space left or right

Tags: c++, arrays, robotframework

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days and googled a lot of different options. None of the code I've found has been able to help me solve my problem; and I'm sorry if this is something that's already been answered elsewhere on the web. I feel like this something I should be able to solve on my own but nothing seems to work. The program that I am designing is a program that is supposed to be for an imaginary robot. The robot is fed random characters from a chute and has to place them in a set of 20 slots. It has a hardware restriction that forces it to put the first block into slot 10. The issue that I'm having is I am trying to create a function that shifts every element within an array one space to the left or the right. I've tried a number of different things. The most success I had was with this bit of code.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char get_block(void)
{
    char block;
    cout << "Enter one block: ";
    cin >> block;
    return toupper(block);
}
//
// Function print_slots
// Prints the contents of the slots array in a well formatted form.
// Input: Array of slots
// Returns: Nothing (void)
//
// Example function call: print_slots(slot_array);

void print_slots(char slots[])
{
    unsigned int j = 1;
    for (j = 1; j <= 20; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << j;
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        cout << setw(3) << slots[j];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Function put_block
// This function stores a character into the character array representing the slots
//
// Inputs:
// block - type char - The character to be inserted into a slot
// position - type unsigned int - index of the slot where the block will go
// array - type char - array of slots containing the blocks
//
// Returns:
// position - type unsigned int - the index of the slot where the block was placed
//
// Example function call:   put_block(block, position, slots);

unsigned int put_block(char block, unsigned int position, char array[])
{
    bool debug = true;
    array[position] = block;
    if (debug)
        cout << "Block " << block << " inserted into slot " << position << endl;
    return position;
}

// Function remove_block
// This function removes a block from the slot array
// The slot where the block is removed is then set to a space
//
// Inputs:
// position - type unsigned int - index of the slot where block is located
// array - type char - array of slots containing the blocks
//
// Returns:
// block - type char - the block removed from the slot
//
// Example function call:   remove_block(position, slots);

unsigned int remove_block(unsigned int position, char array[])
{
    bool debug = true;
    char block = ' ';
    block = array[position];
    array[position] = ' ';  // Reset slot to blank after block removed
    if (debug)
        cout << "Block " << block << " removed from slot " << position + 1 << endl;
    return block;
}


// Function shift_right
// This function increments the index simulating a movement of the robot
// to the next higher slot (index) of the array
//
// Inputs:
// position - type unsigned int - current slot position
//
// Returns:
// position - type unsigned int - The updated position which is input position + 1
//
// Example function call:  position = shift_right(position)
//

unsigned int shift_right(unsigned int position)
{
    bool debug = true;
    position++;
    if (debug)
        cout << "Position right shifted to " << position << endl;
    return position;
}

// Function shift_left
// This function decrements the index simulating a movement of the robot
// to the next lower slot (index) of the array
//
// Inputs:
// position - type unsigned int - current slot position
//
// Returns:
// position - type unsigned int - The updated position which is input position - 1
//
// Example function call: position = shift_left(position)
//

unsigned int shift_left(unsigned int position)
{
    bool debug = true;
    position--;
    if (debug)
        cout << "Position left shifted to " << position << endl;
    return position;
}

// Function robot_ltoreq_slot
// This function compares the value of the block held by the robot
// with the value of the block in a slot
//
// Inputs:
// robot - type char - value of block held by robot
// in_slot - type char - value of block in the slot
//
// Returns:
// true or false
// TRUE if block held by robot is LESS than or equal to the block in slot
// FALSE if block held by robot is GREATER than block in slot
//
// Example function call: if ( compare_blocks(robot_block, slot_block) )
//
bool robot_ltoreq_slot(char robot, char in_slot)
{
    bool debug = true;
    if (debug)
        cout << endl <<  "Comparing robot block " << robot << " with block in slot " << in_slot << endl;
    if (robot <= in_slot)
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Returning true. Robot block LESS than or EQUAL to block in slot. " << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Returning false. Robot block GREATER than block in slot. " << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
// This function checks if the blocks are less than or == to the block in the robots hand
// If the block is equal to it return TRUE if the block is < it return FALSE

bool robot_equal_slot(char robot, char in_slot)
{
    bool debug = true;
    if (debug)
        cout << endl <<  "Comparing robot block " << robot << " with block in slot " << in_slot << endl;
    if (robot == in_slot)
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Returning true. Robot block EQUAL to block in slot. " << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Returning false. Robot block LESS THAN than block in slot. " << endl;
        return false;
    }
}

// Function switch_blocks
// This function switches the block held by the robot with a block in a slot.
// After the switch the robot is holding the block removed from the slot.
//
// Inputs:
// robot - type char - The block to be inserted into a slot
// position - type unsigned int - index of the slot where the block will go
// array - type char - array of slots containing the blocks
//
// Returns:
// robot - type char. The value of the block removed from the slot.
//
// Example function call: block = switch_blocks(block,  position, array);
//

char switch_blocks(char robot, unsigned int position, char array[])
{
    char temp_hold;
    bool debug = true;
    if (debug)
        cout << "Switching blocks " << robot << " with " << array[position] << endl;
    temp_hold = robot;
    robot = array[position];
    array[position] = temp_hold;
    return robot;
}
// Function test_empty
// This function tests the array to determine if a slot is empty (NULL)
// or if the slot contains a blank. The slot array must be intialized to
// all NULL or all blanks (spaces) before any blocks are added.
//
// Inputs:
// position - type unsigned int - index of slot to be tested
//
// Returns:
// true or false as value o function
// TRUE if slot is empty
// FALSE if the slot contains a block
//
// Example function call: if ( test_empty(index, array) )
//


bool test_empty(unsigned int position, char array[])
{
    char blank = ' '; // Blank space
    bool debug = true;
    if  (array[position] == NULL || array[position] == blank)
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Slot " << position << " empty. " << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (debug)
            cout << "Slot " << position << " contains a block " << endl;
        return false;
    }

}
char * move_all_to_right(char slot[], char block){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        if((!(test_empty(i,slot))) && (i != 20)){
            block = switch_blocks(block,i,slot);
            put_block(block,i+1,slot);
            block = switch_blocks(block, i+1, slot);

        }
        else if(i == 20){
            break;
        }
    }
    return slot;

}

int main() {
    char block = get_block();
    char slot[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        slot[i] = NULL;
    }
    int array_size;
    int position;
    char robot;
    int counter = 0;
    int dummy;
    int filled_right;
    bool swapped = false;
    int block_counter = 0;
    int switch_counter = 0;
    //Put the first block from the chute INTO SLOT 10(hardware restriction)
    put_block(block, 10, slot);
    do {
        block = get_block();
        position = counter;
        for(int i = 0; i <sizeof(slot); i++) {
            unsigned int back_to_front = sizeof(slot);
            unsigned int front_to_back = 0;
            if(!(test_empty(back_to_front, slot))){
                do{
                    back_to_front--;
                }while(test_empty(back_to_front, slot));
                do{
                    front_to_back++;
                }while(test_empty(front_to_back,slot));
                for(int i = 0; i <sizeof(slot); i++){
                    if(!(test_empty(i,slot))){
                        block_counter++;
                    }
                }
                if((block <= slot[front_to_back]) && (test_empty(0,slot))){
                    put_block(block, front_to_back - 1,slot);
                    break;
                }
                else if((block > slot[back_to_front]) && (test_empty(19,slot))){
                    put_block(block,back_to_front + 1,slot);
                    break;
                }
                if((block == slot[back_to_front]) && (test_empty(19,slot))){
                    put_block(block,back_to_front + 1,slot);
                    break;
                }
                if(((block < slot[back_to_front]) || (block == slot[front_to_back])) && (test_empty(19,slot))){
                        while((block < slot[back_to_front]) || (block == slot[back_to_front]) &&(block!= NULL)){
                            block = switch_blocks(block,back_to_front-1,slot);
                            back_to_front--;
                            switch_counter ++;
                            if((block == slot[back_to_front]) && (switch_counter != block_counter + 1)){
                                for(int i = back_to_front; i< sizeof(slot); i++){
                                   block = switch_blocks(block,i,slot);
                                   if(test_empty(back_to_front-1,slot)){
                                       break;
                                   }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        block_counter = 0;
        print_slots(slot);
        counter++;
        switch_counter = 0;
    } while (counter < 19);
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(slot); i++){
        cout << slot[i];
    }
}
```

This seemed to work until I introduced redundant characters so I have sense scrapped this approach for something much simpler.

```
int main() {
    char block = get_block();
    char temp_block = ' ';
    char array = *slot;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        slot[i] = NULL;
    }
    int counter = 0;

    //Put the first block from the chute INTO SLOT 10(hardware restriction)
    put_block(block, 10, slot);
    do {
        block = get_block();
        if (block > slot[10]) {
            for(int i = 9; i < 19; i ++){
                if((block > slot[i]) &&!(test_empty(i,slot)) || i == 19){
                    shift_all_left(slot);
                    put_block(block,i,slot);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (block <= slot[10]) {
            for(int i = 10; i > 0; i --){
                if((block <= slot[i]) || i == 0){
                    shift_all_right(slot,20, block);
                    put_block(block,i,slot);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        counter++;
        print_slots(slot);
    }while(counter < 19);
    return 0;
}
```

the shift right function that I have come up with doesn't actually shift the first character of my array and frankly it doesn't work at all.

this is what I have so far.

```
void shift_all_right(char array[],int n, char block){
    int i = 10;
    while(i < n - 1){
        block = switch_blocks(block,array[i],array);
        i++;
    }
    return;
}
```

I still have all of the functions from the first attempt, and I have a shift_all_left function as well that was another idea that I tried that doesn't work as intended. In fact when I combine the two it does some weird stuff in my program.

```
void shift_all_left(char array[]){
    for(int i = 10; i > 0; i--){
        switch_blocks(array[i],array[i-1],array);

    }

}
```

I'm sorry again if this is something that I should be able to figure out but I feel like I'm bashing my head against a brick wall. I really want to be able to solve this without help, but I simply can not.

Comment: You say "shift", so what happens to the hole that is opened up on the extreme left or right after the shift?  What are they replaced with?  Or are you really trying to do a "rotate", and not a shift?  Also, there are too many comments in the code.  At least half the code posted could be eliminated if you removed those comments.

Comment: I'm sorry "rotate" might be better. My goal is to move every block one slot to the left or the right based on the conditions that I set forth. When I lose a block it seems to be that the characters that are already in the array don't get moved over and the new block just replaces the block in slot 10.

Comment: Then consider using [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate).  Also, can you describe what the `n` in the call to `shift_all_right` denotes?  And why `shift_all_left` doesn't have an `n` parameter?

Comment: I think it would be easier if you showed, with a simple character array, what an array would look like before the shift and then after a shift.  There is too much code here, and probably by just looking at the problem at a higher-level, a much easier solution using basic algorithm functions may be available.

Comment: Does something prevent you from putting the first char into the position 10 and then copying it into position 0 and after that put every other where you want?

Answer (score 0):

N is meant to be the size of the array. My idea was that I would always start at slot 10 and sort from there, but the more I think about this it seems like I should start at the position that the block was <= in the array.

```
void shift_right(int position, int size, char array[], char block){
   while(position < size - 1){
block = switch_block(block,array[position+1],array);}
```

am I on the right track?

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment.